# How to use azure cosmos db FeedIterator in the Polly ExecuteAsync()

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0, polly

I have generic Cosmos method to retrieve data from Db and its working fine. Now I want to add Polly to it. I am new to the Polly concept.

So, please help me how to add this FeedIterator in the Polly `ExecuteAsync()` method. Because this is `FeedIterator`, I don't get status code directly. I need to check whether it has more results or not. I am not sure whether I need to retry when there are no results or status code is not as expected.

If I read the feed iterator I am loosing the data, so I am not able to re-read it. I've been googling, but no use.

Here is my code, Can someone please help?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(QueryDefinition query)
{
    try
    {
        var results = new List<T>();
        using (FeedIterator resultsIterator = _container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(query))
        {
            while (resultsIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                using (ResponseMessage response = await resultsIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    dynamic streamResponse = FromStream<dynamic>(response.Content);
                    var rawText = ((JsonElement)streamResponse).GetProperty("Documents").GetRawText();
                    var responseObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(rawText, _jsonSerializerOptions);
                    if (responseObj != null) results.AddRange(responseObj);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please describe what sort of retry behaviour do you want? When should it be trigger? (For example if the parsed list is empty) How many times do you want to retry and how much delay do you want between each retry attempt?

Comment: Hi @Peter Csala, thanks for the response. I need to retry for 5 times and retry delay is 1 second. I think it should trigger when i get error status code from `FeedIterator.RepsoneMessage`. I am not sure that I ever get error status code because this is stream. So i am confused here.

Comment: Well that's a good question. I'm not familiar with this API, so I can't help you determine that. Can't you run some basic tests to confirm or refute your theory?

Comment: That's great, thanks. Can I keep it in the iteration like below.
while (resultsIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
 ResponseMessage response = policy.ExecuteAsync(
                         async () => await resultsIterator.ReadNextAsync());
}

Comment: Please don't do that. I've deleted my previous comment, because first you have to verify that we can use the StatusCode to trigger our retry policy.

Comment: I did some tests my side. Whether I found a record or not in the DB, I am always getting Success status code. That's why I am asking will I ever get error response from the stream.

Comment: As I said I'm not familiar with this API, so I'm not sure based on what do you want to perform a retry. I can image that you would receive an error if you exceed for example the rate limit.

Comment: Do you need any further assistance?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for the correct answer. As I mentioned in my previous comments, I’ve added it within the while loop for now.